# Install lisp kernel in IPython

Tags: linux, lisp, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to install [cl-jupyter](https://github.com/fredokun/cl-jupyter). (Debian)

I've done the following steps:

1. install gcl (`apt-get install gcl`)
2. install sbcl (`apt-get install sbcl`)
3. run command `python3 ./install-cl-jupyter.py`
4. try to run command `sbcl --load ./cl-jupyter.lisp` but I get the following and don't know what to do. I've tried to choose all option, but nothing happend.

Output:

```
This is SBCL 1.2.4.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.

debugger invoked on a SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10039CE993}>:
  READ error during LOAD:

    Package ASDF does not exist.

      Line: 3, Column: 29, File-Position: 150

      Stream: #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM
                for "file /home/ivan/all/language_packages/cl-jupyter-master/cl-jupyter.lisp"
                {10039D64A3}>

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT   ] Abort loading file "/home/ivan/all/language_packages/cl-jupyter-master/./cl-jupyter.lisp".
  1: [CONTINUE] Ignore runtime option --load "./cl-jupyter.lisp".
  2:            Skip rest of --eval and --load options.
  3:            Skip to toplevel READ/EVAL/PRINT loop.
  4: [EXIT    ] Exit SBCL (calling #'EXIT, killing the process).

(SB-C:COMPILER-ERROR SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD :CONDITION #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Package ~A does not exist." {10039D9E83}> :STREAM #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/ivan/all/language_packages/cl-jupyter-master/cl-jupyter.lisp" {10039D64A3}>)
```

5. update file `ipython/your_kernel_name/kernel.json`

from

```
 {"language": "lisp", "display_name": "SBCL Lisp", "argv": ["sbcl", "--non-interactive", "--load", "/home/ivan/all/language_packages/cl-jupyter-master/cl-jupyter.lisp", "/home/ivan/all/language_packages/cl-jupyter-master/src", "/home/ivan/all/language_packages/cl-jupyter-master", "{connection_file}"]}
```

to

```
{
    "argv": [
        "sbcl","--non-interactive", "--load",
        "/path/to/cl-jupyter/cl-jupyter.lisp",
        "/path/to/cl-jupyter/src",
        "/path/to/cl-jupyter",
        "{connection_file}"
    ],
    "display_name": "SBCL Lisp",
    "language": "lisp"
}
```

(information from [here](http://qiita.com/domitry/items/0f5e792929cdc3717282))

Now I can see the `SBCL Lisp` kernel in jupyter but it doesn't work and breaks all the time when I try to write and run smth.

Please, help

Comment: SBCL 1.2.4 is two years old. The current release is SBCL 1.3.9.

Comment: The error says `Package ASDF does not exist`. So you need to make sure that ASDF is loaded. I would anyway start with a newer SBCL and ASDF combination.

Comment: AFAIR, cl-jupyter needs to pull out some dependencies via Quicklisp. So, I would start by installing Quicklisp (https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) and making sure it is loaded when sbcl started. On the side note: you will get smoother experience by pairing sbcl and Org-mode in Emacs.

Comment: Some people, including me, have this problem though: https://github.com/fredokun/cl-jupyter/issues/20 You can try your luck, but it seems it needs some debugging before it can be used. So, I would strongly recommend to use Emacs Org-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it! Now it works fine.

1)I forgot to install quicklisp

2) here i just put right paths to `cl-jupyter.lisp, /src, /cl-jupyter`:

```
{
    "argv": [
        "sbcl","--non-interactive", "--load",
        "/path/to/cl-jupyter/cl-jupyter.lisp",
        "/path/to/cl-jupyter/src",
        "/path/to/cl-jupyter",
        "{connection_file}"
    ],
    "display_name": "SBCL Lisp",
    "language": "lisp"
}
```